# Is this a Functor or Monad?

Tags: haskell

I implemented my own Promise structure in C# and wanted to test the concept in Haskell so after some severe brain workouts (still very new to this) I produced

```
data Promise f a =  PendingPromise f | ResolvedPromise a | BrokenPromise deriving( Show )

class Future p where
        later :: (b -> c) -> p (a -> b) b -> p (a -> c) c
        resolve :: p (a -> b) a -> a -> p (a -> b) b

instance Future Promise where
        later g (PendingPromise f) = PendingPromise (g . f)
        later g (ResolvedPromise a) = ResolvedPromise (g a)
        resolve (PendingPromise f) a = ResolvedPromise (f a)
```

Figuring out how to write this datatype `Promise f a` was a real headache.

Anyway, the `later` method seems to be some sort of Applicative Functor and Promises are supposed to be Monads. Is it possible for me to make `Promise` an instance of some **class** and get this functionality instead of implementing my own class Future?

---

**Edit**
Thanks to @bheklilr the `later` function was proven to be `fmap` in disguise with a little redefinition of the datatype

```
data Promise a b =  PendingPromise (a -> b) | ResolvedPromise b | BrokenPromise

instance Functor (Promise c) where
    fmap f (PendingPromise g) = PendingPromise (f . g)
    fmap f (ResolvedPromise a) = ResolvedPromise (f a)
    fmap f BrokenPromise = BrokenPromise
```

Knowing that (Promise a) is a Functor, it is easier to see why is a Monad.

Comment: Every Monad is an Applicative.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is a monad. The easiest way to see this is observing `Promise f a ≅ Maybe (Either f a)`, thus it's also isomorphic to the transformer equivalent which has an already-proven standard monad instance.

```
type Promise' f = ErrorT f Maybe

promise2Trafo :: Promise f a -> Promise' f a
promise2Trafo (PendingPromise f) = ErrorT . Just $ Left f
promise2Trafo (ResolvedPromise a) = ErrorT . Just $ Right a
promise2Trafo BrokenPromise = ErrorT Nothing

trafo2Promise :: Promise' f a -> Promise f a
trafo2Promise = ... -- straightforward inverse of `promise2Trafo`

instance Applicative Promise where
  pure = trafo2Promise . pure
  fp <*> xp = trafo2Promise $ promise2Trafo fp <*> promise2Trafo xp
```

and so on.

Comment: I wanted to make this as a comment, but it became long so asked as a question.(http://stackoverflow.com/q/23897317/1651941).

Answer (score 6):

What you'll want to do is try to implement the instance for `Functor` and check if it conforms to the [Functor Laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Laws).  Start with the instance:

```hs
instance Functor (Promise f) where
    fmap f (PendingPromise g) = PendingPromise g
    fmap f (ResolvedPromise a) = ResolvedPromise (f a)
    fmap f BrokenPromise = BrokenPromise
```

Does this conform to the Functor Laws?  Since the cases for `PendingPromise` and `BrokenPromise` are always the identity, I'll exclude them for brevity:

```hs
-- fmap id = id
fmap id (ResolvedPromise a) = ResolvedPromise (id a) = ResolvedPromise a

-- fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g
fmap (f . g) (ResolvedPromise a) = ResolvedPromise (f (g a))
fmap f (fmap g (ResolvedPromise a)) = fmap f (ResolvedPromise (g a)) = ResolvedPromise (f (g a))
```

So yes, it does conform to the Functor laws.

Next, see if you can write the `Applicative` and `Monad` instances and prove that they conform to the respective laws.  If you can write an instance that does, then your data type is a `Monad`, irrespective of the `Future` class.

Comment: This line `fmap f (PendingPromise g) = PendingPromise g` should be like this `fmap f (PendingPromise g) = PendingPromise (f. g)`. Is that a problem?

Comment: @CristianGarcia No, it's not supposed to be like that.  Note that `Promise f` is the functor, not `Promise`.  When applying `fmap`, it will change the type from `Promise f a` to `Promise f b`, specifically `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Promise f a -> Promise f b`.  Since the `f` doesn't change, it isn't altered by `fmap`.

Comment: Wow, I will check it out!

Comment: This actually looks a lot like you're trying to implement what amounts to function composition with failure, so since functions are monads, and having BrokenPromise is essentially like having the maybe monad, my intuition is that your type is a monad. If still prove the laws, though, otherwise you won't know if it's well behaved.

Comment: Proving laws is hard. Construct an isomorphism between `Promise f` and `Either (Maybe f)`, and use the latter's `Monad` instance!

Comment: @luqui That is another route, but you still have to prove the isomorphism is an isomorphism!

Comment: @bheklilr with you code I get the error message `Kind mis-match
    The first argument of Functor should have kind * -> *,
    but Promise f has kind *
    In the instance declaration for Functor (Promise f)`

Comment: @CristianGarcia That's odd, are you sure you're using the same data declaration you posted above?  `Promise f` definitely has kind `* -> *`, and it worked on my computer.

Comment: @bheklilr But the point of Promises is to make modifications to a structure now that will only get a concrete value in the future. Your definition `fmap f (PendingPromise g) = PendingPromise g` doesn't to this. To store the modification you need the end result to be `PendingPromise (g . f)` but this is not a proper Functor.

Comment: @CristianGarcia What if instead it was defined with `Promise a b = PendingPromise (a -> b) | ResolvedPromise b | BrokenPromise`?  That might be a bit more in the direction you want.  Alternatively, you could attempt to generalize it to `Promise f b = PendingPromise (f b) | ResolvedPromise b | BrokenPromise`, but that might be harder to write the instances for.

Comment: @bheklilr Look a the signature, later :: (b -> c) -> p (a -> b) b -> p **(a -> c)** c, `f` does change.

Comment: @CristianGarcia Yes, `f` changes, but only the second part of `f`.  Your signature for `later` is actually pretty much the same as that for `fmap`, but not for the data type you've defined.  Your type needs a few modifications before `later` is equivalent to `fmap`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54554/discussion-between-cristian-garcia-and-bheklilr).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code I came up with if its any use to someone. Promise is made an instance of the Functor class, which was the question, but also implements the Future class which to resolve the promise, maybe get its value, and make a new promise.

```
data Promise a b =  Pending (a -> b) | Resolved b | Broken

class Future p where
        resolve :: p a b -> a -> p a b
        getValue :: p a b -> Maybe b
        makePromise :: p a a

instance Future Promise where
        resolve (Pending f) a = Resolved (f a)
        resolve (Resolved a) _ = Resolved a
        resolve Broken _ = Broken

        getValue (Resolved a) = Just a
        getValue (Pending _) = Nothing
        getValue Broken = Nothing

        makePromise = Pending id

instance Functor (Promise a) where
        fmap f (Pending g) = Pending (f . g)
        fmap f (Resolved a) = Resolved (f a)
        fmap f Broken = Broken
```