# Observing isomorphism and then proving them as Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

This question is related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23896527/1651941).

There is a type named `Promise`:

```
data Promise f a =  PendingPromise f | ResolvedPromise a | BrokenPromise deriving (Show)
```

It is stated that:

```
Promise f a ≅ Maybe (Either f a)
```

Now I cannot understand the above expression. How are they sort of
equivalent and isomorphic (and from that how can you conclude that it
is a Monad) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two types `A` and `B` are isomorphic if there's two functions `a2b :: A -> B` and `b2a :: B -> A` such that `a2b . b2a ≡ id` and `b2a . a2b ≡ id`. In the example this is easy to prove: the two functions have basically the same clauses with the sides of `=` turned around, e.g.

```
promise2Trafo (PendingPromise f) = ErrorT . Just $ Left f
trafo2Promise (ErrorT (Just (Left f))) = PendingPromise f
```

so composing the functions in either order gives you the identity function. The crucial thing about an isomorphism is that `a2b x ≡ a2b y` holds exactly iff `x ≡ y`.

Now, how does that help proving typeclass laws? Again taken from the example,

```
instance Applicative Promise where
  pure = trafo2Promise . pure
  fp <*> xp = trafo2Promise $ promise2Trafo fp <*> promise2Trafo xp
```

Now here we need to prove amongst other things

```
  pure id <*> xp ≡ xp
```

Instead of doing this by hand, we exploit the fact that this law has already been proven for `ErrorT f Maybe a`, so we simply introduce some identities:

```
  trafo2Promise $ promise2Trafo (trafo2Promise $ pure id) <*> promise2Trafo xp
 ≡ trafo2Promise $ pure id <*> promise2Trafo xp
```

which is `≡ promise2Trafo xp` iff `pure id <*> promise2Trafo xp ≡ promise2Trafo xp`, which we know is true.

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer so far to invoke inverses.  I would add that the `Applicative` class proofs are perhaps more insightfully put by pointing out that (1) `Maybe (Either f a)` is the composition of `Maybe` and `Either f`, and that (2) [the composition of two `Applicatives` is always an `Applicative` as well](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html); so the isomorphism allows us to trivially implement an `Applicative` instance for `Promise f a`.

Comment: @LuisCasillas: indeed, that's precisely what the writing with monad _transformer_ `ErrorT` expresses. Arguably, it's nicer to talk about compositions than transformers, but functor compositions are awkward to write directly in Haskell.

Comment: What's awkward about `newtype (f :o g) a = Comp (f (g a))`? Or at least what's *more* awkward about that than transformers?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: hm. There's not much awkward about it really, is there? Which makes you wonder why we use transformers all the time...

Comment: I think the *existence* of `transformers`/`mtl` and the lack of monad composition closure drive it. The packages are free marketing and the loss of closure prevents a generic `Monad f, Monad g => Monad (f :o g)` instance. But you can still do a *lot* without that.

Answer (score 8):

A value of type `Promise f a` can be three different things:

1. A value of type `f`, with constructor `PendingPromise`.
2. A value of type `a`, with constructor `ResolvedPromis`,
3. or no value, with constructor `BrokenPromise`.

Similarly, a value of `Maybe (Either f a)` can be three things:

1. A value of type `f`, with 'constructor' `Just . Left`.
2. A value of type `a`, with 'constructor' `Just . Right`.
3. No value, with constructor `Nothing`.

So in that sense the types are isomorphic. The reason that this is not quite true in Haskell has to do with `undefined` values (bottoms), but you can ignore those to make life easier.

`Maybe (Either f a)` can also be seen as `EitherT f (Maybe a)`, which is an instance of `Monad`.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily map a `Promise f a` to a `Maybe (Either f a)` as follows:

- `PendingPromise f -> Just (Left f)`
- `ResolvedPromise a -> Just (Right a)`
- `BrokenPromise -> Nothing`

Given that both `Maybe` and `Either` are instances of `Monad`, it is possible for `Promise` to be expressed as a monad.

A possible implementation could be:

```
instance Monad (Promise f) where
    return a = ResolvedPromise a
    BrokenPromise >>= _ = BrokenPromise
    PendingPromise a >>= _ = PendingPromise a
    ResolvedPromise a >>= f = f a
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf17624bc41a40cd)

Answer (score 1):

There are three possiblilities for `Maybe (Either f a)`:

```
Just (Left f) | Just (Right a) | Nothing
```

this is isomorphic to to `Promise f a`.

This is also the same as

```
EitherT f (Maybe a)
```

which is also a monad.