# Partially Applied Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23895891/2118130) question, in this code

```
data Promise a b =  Pending (a -> b) | Resolved b | Broken

instance Functor (Promise x) where
    fmap f (Pending g) = Pending (f . g)
```

---

**IF**

```
g :: a -> b
```

**then**

```
Pending g :: Promise a b
```

**also**

```
f :: b -> c
```

because of the existence of `f . g`.

**That means**

```
Pending (f . g) :: Promise a c`.
```

**Wrapping up**

```
fmap :: (b -> c) -> Promise a b -> Promise a c
```

---

Now `fmap` alone has this signature (adapted to the above)

```
fmap :: Functor f => (b -> c) -> f b -> f c
```

This only conforms if you assume that `f = Promise a`. While the end product seems reasonable, how do you interpret the type of `f` or equivalently what it the type of a partially applied promise `Promise a`?

Comment: "This only conforms if you assume that `f = Promise a`" -- which is exactly what your `Functor` instance is (`Functor (Promise x)`).

Comment: What do you mean by the type of a partially applied promise `Promise a`? `Promise a` is a type constructor that takes one argument, so it doesn't have a type (it constructs types).

Comment: When you define a function in an instance, the constraint is specialized to the type for which you're defining the instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the type level you have another programming language, *almost*-Haskell. In particular, you can view types as having constructors and being able to be partially applied.

To view this a bit more rigorously, we introduce "types of types" called "kinds". For instance, the type constructor `Int` has kind

```
Int ::: *
```

where I write `(:::)` to read "has kind", though this isn't valid Haskell syntax. Now we also have "partially applied type constructors" like

```
Maybe ::: * -> *
```

which has a function type just like you'd expect at the value level.

---

There's one really important concept to the notion of kinds—values may instantiate types only if they are kind `*`. Or, for example, there exist no values of type `Maybe`

```
x :: Maybe
x = -- .... what!
```

In fact, it's not possible to even express a type of kind other than `*` anywhere where we'd expect that type to be describing a value.

This leads to a certain kind of restriction in the power of "type level functions" in Haskell in that we can't just universally pass around "unapplied type constructors" since they don't always make much sense. Instead, the whole system is designed such that only sensible types can ever be constructed.

But one place where these "higher kinded types" are allowed to be expressed is in typeclass definitions.

---

If we enable `KindSignatures` then we can write the kinds of our types directly. One place this shows up is in class definitions. Here's `Show`

```
class Show (a :: *) where
  show :: a -> String
  ...
```

This is totally natural as the occurrences of the type `a` in the signatures of the methods of `Show` are of values.

But of course, as you've noted here, `Functor` is different. If we write out its kind signature we see why

```
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

This is a really novel kind of polymorphism, higher-kinded polymorphism, so it takes a minute to get your head all the way around it. What's important to note however is that `f` only appears in the methods of `Functor` *being applied* to some other types `a` and `b`. In particular, a class like this would be rejected

```
class Nope (f :: * -> *) where
  nope :: f -> String
```

because we told the system that `f` has kind `(* -> *)` but we used it as though it could instantiate values, as though it were kind `*`.

---

Normally, we don't have to use `KindSignatures` because Haskell can infer the signatures directly. For instance, we could (and in fact do) write

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

and Haskell infers that the kind of `f` must be `(* -> *)` because it appears applied to `a` and `b`. Likewise, we can fail "kind checking" in the same was as we fail type checking if we write something inconsistent. For instance

```
class NopeNope f where
  fmap :: f -> f a -> a
```

implies that `f` has kind `*` *and* `(* -> *)` which is inconsistent.

Comment: Great info! Totally makes sense now by thinking in terms of kinds and kind "functions" or constructors as a language on its own. Do you have any references to an introductions to this topic?

Comment: Sadly, nothing too simple. Eventually this path leads you to dependently typed languages which, should you embark on the not simple journey of learning *those*, greatly intensify this notion. Haskell doesn't have anything nearly so powerful in its type language. You might search things like "type families" or "type functions" for a bit of a taste, though. Generally, if your types are too flexible then it gets hard to know if two types `a` and `b` are equal to one another (and thus have the same values). Haskell restricts the type language to make that notion simpler, computable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any computer language that is a "dependently typed language"? That voodoo seems like using functions on prototypes to create new prototypes in JavaScript, except that in a really conceptual way.

Comment: There are a few: Coq, Agda, Idris. I'd think of any of them eventually as "advanced Haskell".

Comment: @CristianGarcia "Types and Programming Languages" is a great resource for people interested in the theory of type checking. It may not be for complete beginners, but it is quite approachable.

Comment: Ohh... heard of agda, its like a truly pure language where every statement is a mathematical theorem. I think they used it or some other to demonstrate the 4 color theorem in graph theory.

Answer (score 0):

You are only missing the equations for `Resolved` and `Broken`. The only reasonable implementation I can think of is

```
fmap f (Resolved x) = Resolved (f x)
fmap _ Broken = Broken
```

Other than that, your code is fine.

Comment: Yes, they are exactly that. The problem is more of the conceptual understanding of a partial type (if you can call them that). Here the whole type is `Promise a b` but in fmap, `f` is the partial type `Promise a`

Comment: @CristianGarcia Similar to how values have a type, types have a kind (sort of a type of types). The `f` in `Functor f` has kind `* -> *`, where `*` is the kind of "simple types" (e.g. `Int`). The partially applied type constructor `Promise a` has exactly that kind. It needs to be applied to another type of kind `*` to form a type of kind `*`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add to @J. Abrahamson's fantastic answer. A lot of my understanding from Haskell's kind system is from this [diogo castro's blog](https://diogocastro.com/blog/2018/10/17/haskells-kind-system-a-primer/) which I highly recommend.

Coming to the question of Partially Applied Types. Apart from type classes it's also possible to use them in type constructors. Taking an example from the blog.

```hs
data NonEmpty f a = MkNonEmpty { head :: a, tail :: f a }
:k NonEmpty
-- NonEmpty :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
:t MkNonEmpty { head = (3 :: Int), tail = Maybe 3 }
-- :: NonEmpty Maybe Int
```

This is an old question so this might be a recent addition to Haskell. It can be summarized as type constructors can take types and type constructors as arguments.