# Partially applying a type in a type constructor

Tags: haskell

In the book "Learn you a Haskell", chapter 11 we have the introduction of the newtype keyword and it all makes sense to me up to the part where we see the Pair type being made an instance of a Functor.

This discussion begins with a problem statement that "only type constructors that take exactly one parameter can be made an instance of Functor."  I don't understand this statement.  Where is this restriction ever described?

In the context of the discussion we have a type Pair defined as:

```
newtype Pair b a = Pair { getPair :: (a,b) }
```

Given this, I would have thought that we could have used something like:

```
instance Functor (Pair a b) where ...
```

I would have thought that (Pair a b) would have substituted for 'f' in the definition of Functor without any problem.  What keeps this from working?

Next, the author goes on to make Pair an instance of a Functor using the following:

```
instance Functor (Pair c) where ...
```

Here is where I get lost.  I don't recall ever seeing 'partially applying' types to a type constructor before.  I am not really sure what this even means in this context, let alone how it solves the problem identified above it.

I think I have a misconception somewhere but I don't know where to go looking for it.  I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23900121/780350) but it only seems to go part of the way in answering the question.

Comment: Note that the definition of `Functor` is `class Functor f where ...` not `class Functor (f a) where ...`, so instances of `Functor` must look like `instance Functor Maybe where ...` and not like `instance Functor (Maybe a) where ...`.

Comment: It's currying for types.

Comment: The statement "only type constructors that take exactly one parameter can be made an instance of Functor"  is simply an oversimplification (as one would expect of a complete beginner level tutorial). The *kind* of `Functor` is `(* -> *) -> Constraint`, so `instance Functor F` is only valid if `F` has kind `* -> *`. `Pair a b` has kind `*`. `Pair c` has kind `* -> *` and is a type constructor taking a type `x` and giving you the type `Pair c x`, like `Maybe` is a type constructor taking a type `x` and giving you the type `Maybe x`.

Comment: Well, consider a binary function `f`. Now what is `f x`? It's a unary function! The same is true with type constructors. Given a binary type constructor `Pair`, what is `Pair a`? A unary type constructor, and hence it can be made an instance of `Functor`. (partial application of type constructors, however, has some restrictions due to type inference...)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered.  About an hour after I posted this question I started to get a (somewhat fuzzy) picture of the concepts you are outlining.  Although @user2407038, I am unfamiliar with the _kind_ nomenclature you are using, I think I get the concept.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I did start to see that (eventually) but it was just kind of 'thrown in' the book without any explanation.  I have not seen, anywhere else, a description or explanation of partial application of types so I wasn't sure if the concept really translated from functions to types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "only type constructors that take exactly one parameter can be made an instance of Functor." I don't understand this statement. Where is this restriction ever described?

The restriction comes from the type of `fmap` in the definition of `Functor`:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Because the class variable `f` is applied to one argument in `f a`, the type used to instantiate `Functor` must be able to take one parameter. Because the application `f a` is part of a function type, `f` must not take more than one parameter. (There's one more subtle piece about what kinds of arguments `f` can take that's specified here, but I think it's worth skipping that for now; hopefully your tutorial will touch on this subtlety more later.)

> Given this, I would have thought that we could have used something like:
>
> ```
> instance Functor (Pair a b) where ...
> ```
>
> I would have thought that (Pair a b) would have substituted for 'f' in the definition of Functor without any problem. What keeps this from working?

It is once again the type of `fmap` that keeps this from working. Filling in `Pair c d` for `f` (modifying `a` to `c` and `b` to `d` to avoid name clashes), we would get

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Pair c d a -> Pair c d b
```

which doesn't make a lot of sense.

> Here is where I get lost. I don't recall ever seeing 'partially applying' types to a type constructor before.

Well... now you have. =)

> I am not really sure what this even means in this context, let alone how it solves the problem identified above it.

It means basically the same thing partial application at the term level means: `Pair a` is akin to a type function which takes another type as an argument. So, e.g., `Pair a` applied to `Int` would give the `Pair a Int` type. It solves the problem because now we are supplying a "type-function-like" thing rather than a "type-like" thing, so applying it to another type makes sense; that is, the substituted type of `fmap` for a `Pair c` instance would be

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Pair c a -> Pair c b
```

which now makes sense because `Pair c a` and `Pair c b` are sensible types, whereas before `Pair c d a` and `Pair c d b` were over-applied and therefore not sensible types.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  This helps make it clearer.  After staring at the book for a while I began to recognize the similarities between `Pair c` and `Maybe` in the instance definitions for `Functor`.  I had never thought of the missing type in the `Maybe` definition case before (`instance Functor Maybe ...` as opposed to `instance Functor (Maybe a) ...`).  It never jumped out at me so I completely missed what was happening there.  Now that I see it I see that the instance definition for `Maybe` _already was_ a partial application of types.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore the first type parameter more or less like `instance Functor (Pair _ b) where` so that applies `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Pair a c -> Pair b c`?

Comment: @bob No, it is not possible. However, you can use the [`Flip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.5.7/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Flip.html#t:Flip) newtype to get a similar effect.